# CSS simple doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, css

I need to build a very simple doughnut chart  ( 2 values, no animations, pure css)
didn't found anything simple in google ( everything is using animation or many values)

Please help me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20529884/2260614 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468946/2260614

Comment: I need the hole to be transparent for the background and its not possible to to this with the examples..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8nuut/  something like this? You will have to play with rotation and top position to get desired effect... p.s. Here are some helpful ideas to get different shapes: http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css

Comment: http://codepen.io/clintioo/pen/ouxGp

Answer (score 1):

[***Demo***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tvAjy?editors=110)
*CSS*

```
.value {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #FFFFFF, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    position:absolute;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db 0%, #3498db 50%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #3498db), color-stop(50%, #3498db), color-stop(50%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100%, #FFFFFF));/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db 0%, #3498db 50%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db 0%, #3498db 50%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);/* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db 0%, #3498db 50%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);/* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3498db 0%, #3498db 50%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFFFFF 100%);/* W3C */
}
```

The **trick** which makes it work is also it's ***`limitation`***.... Using `linear-gradient` from *`0% to 50% it shows #3498db color and then from 50% to 100% it shows #FFFFFF`* color... To set this dynamically with a perfect look will be a lot difficult...

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can make one using pure CSS, but check out [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut). Theirs is pretty simple, and you can do it with only two values (don't be intimidated by the example).